# unable to delete folder in Linux

Tags: linux, rm

I'm trying to remove directory from my external hard drive that I mounted to the file system.
I'm using the `rm` command with the flag `rf` but I got the following error:

```
Directory not empty
```

Apart from the `rm` command, I tried to remove file which is located in that directory recursively by entering the directory, but I got this strange error:

```
 No such file or directory
```

This is strange because the directory and the file which are located in the directory that I want to remove exist.

Answer (score 3):

This question probably belongs to [Superusers](https://superuser.com/) and not StackOverflow, but try to see what is in the directory by listing hidden files, like;

```
$ ls -la directoryname
```

In Linux/Unix all files which starts with a `.` (dot) are considered hidden files

Another possibility is that you don't have permissions to remove the content -- the `-f` in `rm -rf` will cause those files you cannot remove due to permission issues to be ignored, so you can also try to issue the rm without the `f` option, like

```
rm -r directoryname
```

Comment: i used the rm -r directoryname
but i still got the same error

Comment: you are most likely dealing with a NFS mounted directory which is failing -- is this your personal machine or a company owned machine?

Comment: Also try to do a `ls -lRa directoryname` -- the R option will recursively list all files in the directory so that you can see if anything and what is left

Comment: this is my own machine
and what is NFS mounted directory?

Comment: i have tried to used ls -lRa command,and there are several folder contain in that folder that i want to delete.now what next to do?

Comment: That is a question to ask on superuser.com